# The set_language redirect view for internationalization won't work

Tags: python, django

for i18n I've done these steps,but I can't yet get it worked:
in `settings.py`:

```
LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'
SITE_ID = 1
USE_I18N = True
USE_L10N = True
LANGUAGES = (
    ('fa', gettext('Persian')),
    ('en', gettext('English')),
)
LOCALE_PATHS = (
    'fa/LC_MESSAGES/django.po',
    'fa/LC_MESSAGES/django.mo',
    'en/LC_MESSAGES/django.po',
    'en/LC_MESSAGES/django.mo',
    '$PYTHONPATH/django/conf/locale/fa/LC_MESSAGES'
)
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware',
        'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
        'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
        'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfResponseMiddleware',
        'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
        'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
)
```

I've built mesage fiels in my app folder and compiled theme.
I have created translation strings in the template.
and to switch between languages I have this in my template:

```
<form action="/i18n/setlang/" method="post" class="forms">
{% csrf_token %}
<input name="next" type="hidden" value="/next/page/" />
<select name="language" id="select_langauge" class="m_show hide">
{% for lang in LANGUAGES %}
    {% if lang.0 != '' %}
        <option value="{{lang.0}}">{{lang.1}}</option>
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
</select>
<input type="submit" value="Go" />
</form>
```

and in `urls.py` :

```
(r'^i18n/', include('django.conf.urls.i18n'))
```

but when I submit this form to switch between languages,I have this error:

```
Page not found (404)
Request Method:     GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8080/next/page/
```

Is there anything that I've ommited?

thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 2):

I think Django tries redirect you to /next/page/

```
<input name="next" type="hidden" value="/next/page/" />
```

But, you have not this path in your urls, isn't it?

Comment: Here is this [function](https://code.djangoproject.com/browser/django/trunk/django/views/i18n.py#L12). Put existing path or just remove this input

Comment: I've used code in django documentations,I don't now what's /next/page for and how can I handle it.

Comment: Ok. Just remove this line. It will redirect you back to main page ("/")

Comment: It didn't work,I put action="." but it didn't work and after returning it deselect my choice,How can I handle this part of code?

Comment: action should be "/i18n/setlang/". There is not part for set correct selection in your code. Now this is doesnt matter. Try to find out if language changed.

Comment: when action is "/i18n/setlang/" , page redirect to this path after submitting,and this path doesn't exist,would U mind describing more?

Answer (score 1):

You have to give the absolute paths to the **locale** - the folder that contain your translations. It goes something like this:

```
LOCALE_PATHS = (
    'C:/abolute_path_to_your_project/.../locale/',
)
```

The folder **locale** should contain your translations like this:

```
.../locale/
         - en/LC_MESSAGES/django.po
                          django.mo
         - fr/LC_MESSAGES/django.po
                          django.mo
```